# Determination of an uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which of the following sets are uncountable?

1. $\{f:f:\mathbb N\to \{1,2\}\}$
2. $\{f:f:\{1,2\}\to \mathbb N\} $
3. $\{f:f:\mathbb N\to \{1,2\}, f(1)\leq f(2)\}$
4. $\{f:f:\{1,2\}\to \mathbb N, f(1)\leq f(2)\} $

I think the set given in option 1 is uncountable as this is the set of all sequences with its entries 1 and 2. Am I right or some more sets are also uncountable?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have sets $A,B$ with $|A|=\alpha$ and $|B|=\beta$ the cardinality of the set $\{f:f:A \to B\}$ is $\beta^{\alpha}$ Therefore,

1)$|\{f:f:\Bbb{N} \to \{1,2\}\}|=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$ which is the cardinality of $\Bbb{R}$ and it is therefore uncountable.

You can do 2) in a similar way, bare in mind that $\aleph_{0}^2=\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0=\aleph_0$.

Observe that the 3) is a subset of 1) and 4) is a subset of 2). With this observation you can trivialy find that 4) is countable. Can you do number 3)?

Comment: I am confused with this number 3. Any help?